# Rails Console Complex queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I would like to post a subcategory using subsequent query like this:

```
Gender.where(gender: 'Masc').categories.where(name: 'clothes').subcategories.create([{ name: 't-shirt' }])
```

but  show  this error!

> rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `subcategories' for
>   Category

I searched but could not find out how to create a data using a chained query.

```
Gender Model:

class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :gender, use: [:slugged, :history]

  has_many :categories
  has_many :subcategories, through: :categories
  has_many :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subcategories
  attr_accessible :gender, :categories_attributes, :subcategories_attributes,


end
```

Answer (score 3):

`where(name: 'clothes')` returns a query, not a model instance. Presumably you have a `has_many :subcategories` in your categories and category names are unique so you'd use `find_by` to find the clothes category and then call `subcategories` on that. Similarly for looking up the gender:

```
Gender.find_by(gender: 'Masc')  # This gives you a single Gender instance
      .categories
      .find_by(name: 'clothes') # and then a single Category here
      .subcategories
      .create(name: 't-shirt')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mu_is_too_short, but i don't know why still show:

NoMethodError:   Gender Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "genders".* FROM "genders" WHERE "genders"."gender" = 'Masc'
undefined method `categories' for #<Gender::FriendlyIdActiveRecordRelation:0x007f261c2890d0>

Comment: What does your `Gender` model look like?

Comment: So you're saying `Gender.find_by(gender: 'Misc')` and FriendlyId is giving you a relation? Really? That doesn't make any sense to me and I've never heard of FriendlyId so I don't know what it is doing. Are you sure you're not saying `Gender.where(gender: 'Misc')` still?

Comment: Well, i have no idea why the FriendlyId is behaving this way either!

I change to find_by and the same happens. i gonna, add a gender_id on subcategory to check if this problem is the association problem.